# Need some component to allow 17 A pulses at 10 Hz, but clamp or trip if the current goes continuous

Tags: current-source, current-limiting, constant-current

I would like to protect some equipment that gets damaged when it continuously pulls 17 A for more than 2 seconds. I would like to react to the current within around 1 second.

The supply voltage is 48V DC.

The duty cycle of the pulses (0.77%) makes the mean current in the milliamps. I am currently using a 1 A circuit breaker to detect if the current becomes continuous, but the mechanical component makes a ticking sound which is not good.

Can anyone think of a component that would work better? I don't want to build a circuit but buy something that may be placed in series. It doesn't have to trip; if it could limit the continuous current to 1 A but allow pulses of 17-20 A that would be OK too.

Comment: I designed a circuit very similar to this once a long time ago. The basic idea was that if the pulse went continuous, an SCR would fire, thus shorting out a fuse which would then blow very quickly. This was a permanent and extreme solution to the problem.

Comment: What is the duty cycle in your application? How long are the pulses?

Comment: What is the supply voltage?

Comment: Do you have any external means to trip or does the device need to sit in series and break the current itself?

Comment: A simple RC with a Schmitt trigger might do it (maybe even a transistor).

Comment: I would like for it to sit in series ideally. Also a complete product, I don't want to build a circuit.

Comment: How fast does it need to act?

Comment: What's the problem with the ticking sound? A self resetting circuit breaker seems like a good solution for your problem?

Comment: Using a larger breaker might help with the ticking sound, or a thermal-only breaker instead of thermal-magnetic.,

Comment: I suspect that the magnetic component is being actuated and hitting the trigger (as 17A is well above the magnetic threshold for most 1A breakers), but without enough force to actually trip due to the short duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a thermal circuit breaker was the best. No sound plus lowest current drop.

Answer (score 1):

There are positive-temperature-coefficient resistors that
can make a resets-when-it-cools current limiter such as you describe, but they require some attention to the heat
shedding and heat capacity of the surroundings of the
device.

[Bourns PTC device](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/MF-GSMF.pdf)

The use of these is an exercise in heat control
more than of electrical design.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting some of these components! Will let you know of the outcome.

Comment: This didn't work.